# Add Unauthenticated Pages to a AppService with AAD enabled

Tags: c#, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have AAD Oauth enabled using instructions from this URl. it works as designed and explained here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad  using Configure with express settings

Howerver i would like to add some URLS to my site that does not require Authentication or I would like only certain pages to be authenticated. This setup makes every single page authenticated and some that are not. How do add rules to avoid the AAD auth for certain pages?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `Action to take when request is not authenticated` to `allow anonymous`. Then in your root folder include the file `authorization.json` or `authorization.yaml`

Within that file you can define the rules to exclude/include urls that require authentication/authorisation.

See https://azure.github.io/AppService/2016/11/17/URL-Authorization-Rules.html for examples

Comment: I have tried this approach of creating authorization.json, but its not working. All the urls are requiring authentication. I have also enabled authentication of Azure AD in authentication section

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if we use app service easy auth, we can not  ensure which pages require Authentication. So we need to implement it with our own code. The detailed steps are as below.

1. Register an Azure AD application 
   When the Register an application page appears, enter your application's registration information:

   a. In the `Name` section, enter a meaningful application name that will be displayed to users of the app, for example `ASPNET-Quickstart`.

   b. Add `<your web app url>` in Redirect URI, and click Register.

   c. From the left navigation pane under the Manage section, select `Authentication`
   Under the Implicit Grant sub-section, select ID tokens.
   And then select Save.
2. Update project
   a. Install package

   ```
   Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
   Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
   Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
   ```

   b. Add OWIN Startup Class

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebappAD.Startup))]

namespace WebappAD
{
   public class Startup
   {


       string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

       string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];



       static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

       string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
           app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

           app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
           app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
               new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
               {
               // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
               ClientId = clientId,
               Authority = authority,
               RedirectUri = redirectUri,

                   // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                   PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
               Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
               // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
               ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
               // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
               // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
               // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
               TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                   {
                       ValidateIssuer = false // This is a simplification
               },
               // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
               Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                   {
                       AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                   }
               }
           );
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="context"></param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
       {
           context.HandleResponse();
           context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
           return Task.FromResult(0);
       }
   }
}
```

c. Update web.config

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
 <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="ClientId" value="Enter_the_Application_Id_here" />
<add key="redirectUri" value="Enter_the_Redirect_URL_here" />
<add key="Tenant" value="common" />
<add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
</appSettings>
```

d. add signin method in your controller

```
public void SignIn()
       {
           if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
           {


               HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                   new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                   OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
           }
       }
```

e. Use it

```
[Authorize] // add it on the method you need to authenticate
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp)

Comment: @thinkara Do you have any other concerns?